# How to avoid circular loop in Linq to Sql query?

Tags: c#, json.net, circular-reference

Currently I am using `[JsonIgnore]` property to avoid circular references in the models. But I think, it will be applied in all implementations.

Right now I am using like this-

I have two Models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EstimatedEndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ServiceObject> ServiceObjects { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RegardingUser { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsProjectDeleted { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int? ServiceObjectTemplateID { get; set; }

}
```

One another Model is-

```
public class ServiceObject
{
    public int ServiceObjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string RegardingUser { get; set; }
    public int? ParentServiceObjectID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentServiceObjectID")]
    public virtual List<ServiceObject> ServiceObjects { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }<--------------------------- 
    public virtual List<ServicePicture> ServicePictures { get; set; }
    public bool IsServiceObjectDeleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to apply `JsonIgnore` property or any other property In Linq to Sql query itself. I mean I want to apply it dynamically.

The Query is like-

```
var projectList = (from pro in context.Projects.All
                   select pro).ToList();
```

I want to apply conditionally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attributes must be applied at compile time, so you can't add them dynamically.

Comment: It means it will be applied only in models?

Comment: Yes you have to apply them to your properties at compile time.

Comment: Your problem has NOTHING to do with Linq-to-SQL and everything to do with Json.Net

Comment: Are you using entity framework by any chance?

Comment: @Mrchief Is Linq-to-SQL == Entity Framework?

Comment: @Aron: Its not. Which is why I'm asking. Often, it is better to understand the problem before building the solution. I have a feeling what the OP is asking is not his real problem.

Comment: @Mrchief The problem should be serialization and nothing to do with the DAL (separation of concern and least surprise). This should be solved with Json.Net and not with LinqToSQL.

Comment: @Mrchief Yes I am using Entity Framwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your inputs and as I suspected, what you're seeing is a typical EF Code First issue. EF generates *dynamic* proxies for each of your entity so that it can track changes to it. However, this makes **serialization difficult** since they are created as `dynamic` objects. There are few ways to avoid this:

**Option A: Disable proxy creation just for the particular query:**

```
// disable proxy creation just for the duration of query
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

// do the query, serialize, go crazy!

// enable proxy again. or if your context goes out of scope after this call, then you can ignore re-enabling.
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

**Option B: If you are not going to modify and update the entity at some later point**

```
var entity = context.Where(...);  // or whatever query

// detach entity
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

**Option C: Avoid proxies by modifying type definition:**

If you create sealed type or type without virtual properties, EF will not create a proxy since there 
is nothing for the proxy to do.

```
public sealed class Project {...}

// or make it non virtual
...
public List<ServiceObject> ServiceObjects { get; set; }
...
```

**Note** that in this case, you have to load related objects manually:

```
context.Projects.Include(p => p.ServiceObjects).ToList();
```

**Option D: Disable proxy creation permanently:**

```
// in your initializer or DbContext class' constructor
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

**Note**: If proxy creation is disabled, EF will not tracked changes automatically. You can [manually track them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456848(v=vs.100).aspx) using the Snapshot method.

You can follow one or more of these options depending on your design. I usually stick with option A or B.

Comment: Thank you for giving me several solutions. All the solutions were good. I hope all these ways are standard ways. :)

Comment: These are all the officially documented ways that I know of.

Comment: I think `ProxyCreationEnabled ` is for Entity Framework only and not Linq to SQL, the questioner is asking about Linq to SQL

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien I confirmed with OP about EF. Check comments on the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

XY problem. Your actual problem is "I want to control at runtime what properties get serialized".

The most common method of controlling what properties are serialized is using the `JsonIgnoreAttribute`. However as others have commented, attributes are applied at compile time, and cannot normally be modified at runtime (nor would you want to, since it would in effect be a global setting being changed at runtime, you would run into a ton of Threading issues).

Instead, the answer is to use the `IContractResolver` interface to change the serialization behavior.

```
public class OmitPropertyContractResolver
       : IContractResolver
{
    private readonly string[] _ignoredProperties;
    private readonly IContractResolver _resolver;

    public OmitPropertyContractResolver(IContractResolver resolver, params string[] ignoredProperties)
    {
        _ignoredProperties = ignoredProperties;
        _resolver = resolver;        
    }
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = _resolver.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return properties
               .Where(p => _ignoredProperties.Contains(p.Name) == false)
               .ToList();
    }
}
```

The other possibility is to use  [`ReferenceLoopHandling`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationSettings.htm) setting in your Json.net settings.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer(
                      new JsonSerializerSetting()
                               { 
                                   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
                               } );
```

This will serialize each object only once.

The last option is to use `ItemReferenceLoopHandling`. This is a non-standard way of serializing (and deserializing) Object-Graphs (note, graph and not tree) which have circular references.

The disadvantage of this method is that it is non-standard, and might not work on the client end.

Comment: Hmm... Actually my application is client side application completely.